# Private class variable requiring pointer?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm putting together a C++ class, but I'm running into an error which I can fix, but don't quite understand.

I'm trying to use the following header (main.h):

```
#include <git2.h>

class Test
{    
public:
private:
    git_repository gitRepo;
};
```

and the following file (main.cpp):

```
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Test test;
}
```

But it is giving me a "Test::gitRepo' uses undefined struct 'git_repository'". The struct isn't actually undefined though, because if I use a pointer to the struct instead of the struct itself...

```
git_repository * gitRepo;
```

...it compiles fine.

The type declaration for git_repository is as follows:

```
typedef struct git_repository git_repository;
```

I grepped the entire include tree, and that's the only typedef or struct definition in the code. Would this suggest that the actual struct definition is hidden inside of the actual library implementation, but not included in the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the compiler see's `git_repository` as an **Incomplete type**.
The compiler cannot see definition of the structure `git_repository` so it treats it as an Incomplete type. This means you cannot ask the compiler to do any operation which needs the compiler to know the size or layout of structure. You can still declare a pointer to the structure because pointers to structures always have the same size irrespective of which structure it is.

If you need to create an instance of the structure the compiler **must** see the definition of the structure and you **must** include the header which defines the type.

Comment: I'm still unsure why the main wouldn't have issues with the type though; I'm using the same headers in both, so I'm not sure why one is  able to determine the struct definition, and the other can't.

Comment: @Shookit: You will have to strip down your code, remove out all the other stuff and compile again trying to reproduce the problem. If you do reproduce it post the stripped down minimalistic code here in the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good suggestion, I'll give that a try in a bit here.

Answer (score 3):

You **can** declare a *pointer* to `T` even though type `T` is incomplete (i.e., if you have provided only a declaration for it, but not a definition), because the size of pointers does not depend on the size of `T` and as long as you do not access members of `T` through that pointer (which is the case here, since you only declare a variable of type `T*`), the compiler does not need to have any specific knowledge about `T`.

However, you **cannot** declare a variable of type `T` if `T` is incomplete, because the compiler needs to know the size of `T`, and for that it needs to see `T`'s definition.

Comment: @Shookit Then obviously the "main method" has the definition of `git_repository` in scope, while the definition of `GitWatcher` does not.

Comment: @Shookit: Before your `main` method can declare a variable, there is probably a point where you directly or indirectly `#include` the header which contains the definition of `git_repository`.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I moved all of the headers from my .cpp file to my .h file, and the .cpp file just includes the .h file (so they have the same set of includes). Still have the same issues though.